# Implicit negation in conditional phrases with なら

Tags: grammar

This title is the only concise way I thought of to ask this: To my understanding, there is no negating function of `なら` in a sentence, but the translated lyrics suggest otherwise. Is it some sentence construction that I'm missing? (Sorry if the title isn't very descriptive)

This is the official translation of the lyrics, however, I find that the first line sounds off to me:

> 心の声をそのままあなたに届けられたなら
>
> If I **couldn't** send you the messages from the bottom of my heart,
>
> 言葉も口も元気な芝居も意味なかったね
>
> my words, my mouth, my energetic vibe would lose their meanings.

I broke the sentence down like so:

- The whole sentence is connected positively, where `なら` should serve
  as something like an 'if, then' conjunction, instead of 'if not,
  then'.
- `そのまま` contrasts with `言葉`,`口`,`元気な芝居`, where currently the
  antecedent clause is not true.
- `-られた` does not negate the verb.

So my understanding of the phrase is more along the lines of:

> If my deepest feelings could just reach you as is,
>
> then there wouldn't be a need for words, speaking, or pretending to be energetic.

where, the negation of "couldn't" is nowhere to be found.

**EDIT:**

Upon revisiting this, and seeing that the Chinese version also contains the negation. I'm pretty confident that this is not a mistake.

If so, then I'm postulating this breakdown:

> 心の声をそのままあなたに届けられたなら
>
> (voice within heart)(keep on like that)(you)(were reached)(then)
>
> If my deepest feelings can reach you only as it is (which is not ideal) now,

With this, そのまま is the undesirable outcome, which fulfils the "implicit negation".

Comment: I'm tempted to chalk it up to stylistic translation or smth

Comment: Your analysis seems more convincing to me.

Comment: I'm not even sure if those two lines are supposed to make up one sentence...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding is just fine. There is no such thing as "implicit negation with なら". (I confirmed the original translation is flagged as "official" [here](https://vocaloidlyrics.fandom.com/wiki/%E8%9B%8D%E3%81%AF%E3%81%84%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8B%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F_(Hotaru_wa_Inakatta)), but I couldn't find anything about how it was translated.)